# Shoretel - Maximum length of name for Shoregear SG-50

Tags: switch, voip, shoretel

For a Shoregear SG-50, what is the maximum number of characters you can use for the name of the switch? We'd like to use 20 characters but before we do, are there any practical limitations of a name this long?

How many characters are allowed in this field:

[image: How many characters are allowed in this field?]

Answer (score 0):

In the database, the name field is called HostName and is defined as 255 characters long. The Description field is called SwitchName in the database and only 50 characters long.